# Calculating with dynamic textboxes

Tags: javascript

I am working with dynamic textboxes. With this dynamic textboxes I want to perform a calculation:

The calculation is simple. I want to calculate the total value of the textboxes.

In my example I am using 3 textboxes with the id`s:`value1`,`value2`and`value3`.

The calculation I want to make is: 
`value1` + `value2` + `value3` = `total`

In my javascript I dont want to define all these value`s becouse the possible id`s numbers are unlimited.

So my question is. How can I get the total count of the values without defining each ID.

Here is my script:

```
Items:<br />
<input type="text" name="value[]" id="value1" placeholder="Value 1" onChange="getPrice(this.value)" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="value[]" id="value2" placeholder="Value 2" onChange="getPrice(this.value)" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="value[]" id="value3" placeholder="Value 3" onChange="getPrice(this.value)"/> <br />
<br />
Total: <br />
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" placeholder="Total"/> <br />

<script>
function getPrice() {         
  var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("value").value);

  var totalValue = numVal1;
  document.getElementById("total").value = totalValue.toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8vhot05u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go over all `value[]` inputs and sum them up:

```
 let total = 0;
 for(const el of document.getElementsByName("value[]"))
   total += +el.value;

 document.getElementById("total").value = total;
```